# RecyclerView with swipe gesture actions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, swipe

I'm a new Android developer and I would like to use swipe actions on a RecyclerView Items like the video below I found on material.io (please see link below)

I found a lot of libraries but often swipe gesture is for remove items or reveal buttons.
It's not what I want. Could you please help me to create the same behaviour as shown in this below example ("elastic" effect, swipe left or right, background color animation with icon update) ?

Maybe a library already exists??

Thanks for your help

https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1gSz-L39Or4aM8GhQn0ZhnUkaV5E-cyoc%2Ftype-action-swipe.mp4

Answer (score 0):

you should use this [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper)

this gives swipe functionalty for recyclerView items

check out this [Example](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/)

Comment: Thank you for help. Any idea how to create the background animation?

Comment: If this Answer is good please mark it as answer and ask separate question.. i am pretty sure there a lot of examples for animations. Thank you

Comment: Please consider providing the contents of the link within your answer - links can go down or be invalid at any point.